# Strange unselectable character in JavaScript output

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript object which I'm using to populate a form element (with jQuery):

```
var attribute = { name : '̈́Type' };
$('#container').html('<input type="text" value="'+attribute.name+'/>');
```

But the output shows a strange character which is not selectable:

[image]

This character is also present when trying:

```
alert(attribute.name); //in Firefox
console.log(attribute.name); //in Chrome
```

My JavaScript file has UTF8 encoding.

What is this character and how do I make it go away?

Comment: `name : '̈́Type' ` you have that character in your attribute text. If you don't want it - remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strange character is a unicode diacritic (`\u0344`) and is applied to the first single quote `'` on the `{ name : '̈́Type' }`declaration.

Just delete the offending single quote and retype it.

You have got something akin to this:

```
var strange_character = '  \u0344';

var attribute = { name : 'Type' };
$('#container').html('<input type="text" value="'+strange_character + attribute.name+'"/>');
```

Answer (score 1):

This strange character has code `U+0344` is called `COMBINING GREEK DIALYTIKA TONOS`.

**Description:**

> [U+0344](http://codepoints.net/U+0344) was added to Unicode in version 1.1. It belongs to the block 
>   [Combining Diacritical Marks](http://codepoints.net/combining_diacritical_marks) in the [Basic Multilingual Plane](http://codepoints.net/basic_multilingual_plane).
>
> This character is a [Nonspacing Mark](http://codepoints.net/search?gc=Mn) and inherits its script property
>   from the preceding character.
>
> The glyph is a [Canonical](http://codepoints.net/search?dt=can) composition of the glyphs [U+0301](http://codepoints.net/U+0301) and [U+0308](http://codepoints.net/U+0308). It has a
>   [Ambiguous](http://codepoints.net/search?ea=A) East Asian Width. In bidirectional context it acts as
>   [Nonspacing Mark](http://codepoints.net/search?bc=NSM) and is not mirrored. In text [U+0344](http://codepoints.net/U+0344) behaves as
>   Combining Mark regarding line breaks. It has type [Extend](http://codepoints.net/search?SB=EX) for sentence
>   and [Extend](http://codepoints.net/search?WB=Extend) for word breaks. The Grapheme Cluster Break is [Extend](http://codepoints.net/search?GCB=EX).

**REF:** http://codepoints.net/U+0344

Answer (score 1):

If you will zoom on your question really close, you will see its already there. You just need to retype it.[image: See this screenshot]